# Boost skewness c++ example

Tags: c++, boost, boost-accumulators

Any one have an example of using the boost [skewness](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/accumulators/statistics/skewness.hpp) and [weighted skewness](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/accumulators/statistics/weighted_skewness.hpp) accumulators? 
All I found was the source code, and any examples of using this would be great.

any one know how to get these to work for matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of using `skewness` here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/stat_tut/weg/binom_eg/binomial_coinflip_example.html